# Meteor Basics: Display Information about specific user in profile page

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react

I'm using React and Meteor.

I have a form that allows a user to register. When a user registers, he/she enters info such as their bio, facebook url etc etc. I use Accounts.createUser to register.

When a user visits /user/:userId, I want to display the info about the user with id userID.

I am totally lost on how to combine this with withTracker, and if withTracker is even necessary.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withTracker} from 'react-meteor-data';

class Profile extends Component {

render() {
   return(
       <div>
       <p>Username: </p>
       <p>Bio: </p>
       </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Profile;
```

Where do I go from here? I took a look at this https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#introduction
but honestly I don't get it.

I guess my questions are:
1. How do I set up a subscription to Meteor.users? (I removed autopublish and insecure)
2. .... How do I pass the data into the profile container?

Answer (score -1):

You need neither subscribing to `Meteor.users` nor implementing `withTracker`, as `Meteor.user` is already a reactive data source and managed by `Meteor.Accounts` not via pub/sub. You should read official [Meteor Users Accounts page](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html), first. I also advice you to exercise [Meteor & React simple tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app).